# API found & working in postman but not found when called via web application in browser

Tags: typescript, rest, vuejs3

Summary:

Tried api call via postman and this is working.
Tried api call via typescript in our vue3 project but browser says its not found (404).

Other api calls work just fine. The problem is that this specific api is behind a nginx reverse proxy.

[Postman API Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Y0v.png)

API Call via vue project

```
async postOrder ({ rootState }, {cartPowerKey}: { cartPowerKey: string }): Promise<void> {
await API.Req('PUT', `https://(URL)/Flow_API/Orders/CreateOrder?CartPowerKey=${cartPowerKey}&UseSpaceDevEnvironment=true`, {token: rootState.token})}
```

[Browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eMBc.png)
My question is why postman can call the api just find but via our vue3 application we see that it cannot be found why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The request is blocked by [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). In other words, the remote server only allows requests from a limited set of URLs, localhost is not one of them. You should contact the remote server's admin to whitelist your host

Comment: In the second screenshot i added you can see the CORS header: access-control-allow-headers: *. This is the one i need right?

Comment: Yes, please disregard my comment   The only other logical thing I can think of is that the remote server doesn't support OPTIONS. You could try sending an OPTIONS request through Postman as well and see if that works @Daan